# PHP: how do check time within specific range without using date?

Tags: php, time

Just go to direct example because I'm bad at explaining thing and sorry for it.
So for example you want to check is specific time is within range?

```
sample range
- 20:00 - 05:00
result : 
  - 19:59 is false
  - 21:00 is true
  - 00:00 is true
  - 04:00 is true
  - 05:01 is false

- 07:00 - 16:00
result :
  - 06:59 is false
  - 09:00 is true
  - 12:00 is true
  - 16:01 is false
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to compare times without dates. You should pass dates as well, otherwise it is not possible to validate for example `04:00`.
Here's the code:

```
function in_time_range($start, $end, $check)
{
    $start = new DateTime($start);
    $end = new DateTime($end);
    $check = new DateTime($check);

    return $check >= $start && $check <= $end;
}

var_dump(in_time_range('25-08-2016 20:00:00', '26-08-2016 05:00:00', '25-08-2016 21:00:00')); // true
var_dump(in_time_range('25-08-2016 20:00:00', '26-08-2016 05:00:00', '26-08-2016 06:00:00')); // false
```

Edit:

Just in case - this is not possible IF you're giving times from different days. Your example was `22:00` to `05:00` so I asssumed you're comparing times from two different days.

If you want to compare times from the same day, then it's totally possible with the following code:

```
function in_time_range($start, $end, $check)
{
    $start = new DateTime($start);
    $end = new DateTime($end);

    if ($end < $start) {
        $tmp = $start;
        $start = $end;
        $end = $tmp;
        unset($tmp);
    }

    $check = new DateTime($check);

    return $check >= $start && $check <= $end;
}

var_dump(in_time_range('20:00', '05:00', '19:00')); // true
var_dump(in_time_range('20:00', '05:00', '04:00')); // false
```

Comment: in fact that's wrong. you can't just reverse it. if you start 20:00 - 05:00 then 21:00 should be true but your code result is false.

Answer (score -2):

and here is the code for PHP and logic, actually it's really simple

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
$startPush = "22:00";
$endPush = "17:30";
for($i = 0;$i < 24;$i++){
    $hour = str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $timeNow = "{$hour}:00";
    $isOK = ($startPush <= $timeNow and $endPush >= $timeNow);
    if ($startPush > $endPush) {
        $bigTime = ($startPush <= $timeNow and "24:00" >= $timeNow);
        $litTime = ("00:00" <= $timeNow and $endPush >= $timeNow);
        $isOK = ($bigTime or $litTime);
    }

    echo "{$timeNow} is ".($isOK ? "PASS" : "ERROR")."<br>";
}
```

result

```
00:00 is PASS
01:00 is PASS
02:00 is PASS
03:00 is PASS
04:00 is PASS
05:00 is PASS
06:00 is PASS
07:00 is PASS
08:00 is PASS
09:00 is PASS
10:00 is PASS
11:00 is PASS
12:00 is PASS
13:00 is PASS
14:00 is PASS
15:00 is PASS
16:00 is PASS
17:00 is PASS
18:00 is ERROR
19:00 is ERROR
20:00 is ERROR
21:00 is ERROR
22:00 is PASS
23:00 is PASS
```